# Problems with CursorAdapter and query

Tags: java, android, android-cursoradapter

I'm making a StudentManager application.

- In MainActivity.java, when I touch on floating button, It will switch to EditActivity.java. Then, in EditActivity.java, if I press done button, sendToMain() will get data from EditActivity and send to MainActivity, then DatabaseHandler.java will store data in database.
- The problem happened when I tried to create a cursor to populate ListView from database. I created returnCursor() in DatabaseHandler.java, then I used it in MainActivity, and an error came. I don't know whether my cursor's query is wrong or StudentCursorAdapter.java is wrong or this error comes from something else.

MainActivity.java

```
 public void showStudent()
{
    Cursor cursor = databaseHandler.returnCursor();
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));

    Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //to make sure cursor can be used
    StudentCursorAdapter studentCursorAdapter = new StudentCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
    studentCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    MlistView1.setAdapter(studentCursorAdapter);
}
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public Cursor returnCursor()
{
    //String selectQuery = "select * from " + TABLE_STUDENTS;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_STUDENTS,
            new String[] {KEY_IDNUM, KEY_NAME, KEY_BIRTHYEAR, KEY_ISMALE, KEY_CLASSNAME},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor;
}
```

StudentCursorAdapter.java

```
public class StudentCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter 
{

public StudentCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor)
{
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
{
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_layout, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
{
    TextView CtextView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CtextView1);
    TextView CtextView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CtextView2);
    ImageView CimageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.CimageView1);

    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
    String className = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("classname"));

    CtextView1.setText(name);
    CtextView2.setText(className);
}
}
```

This is my project (written in Android Studio 2.2.3), branch 3-8_Fe-6-2017
https://github.com/nhatnguyenduy/StudentManager/tree/3-8_Fe-6-2017

[I think error comes from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dP6H.jpg)

Please help. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please forgive my mistake because this is the first time I've asked a question in stackoverflow. I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my lecturer, I knew where I did wrong. Because I used CursorAdapter, so "_id" must appear in my database, but I didn't make that happen.
For more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html